# Tomcat - Multiple webapps folders

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

Is it possible to have multiple folders where I can place applications to be deployed?

How are these defined?

And is it possible to restrict one folder to just be applications for "domain.com" and no other domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `conf/server.xml`:

```
  <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

You can nest `<Host>` elements within the `<Engine>` element and have different ones corresponding to different virtual hosts, different `appBase`'s etc.

[Here's the documentation on the `<Host`> element.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html)